# Not able to SSH EKS Worker Nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have create EKS cluster as specified in
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started.html

Added worker nodes 
as specified in above link Step 3: Launch and Configure Amazon EKS Worker Nodes

In security Group also I added rule for enabling ssh to worker nodes. 
When I tried to login to worker node with 'ec2-user' username and with valid key SSH Login is not happening.

Can anyone help me in debugging this issue ?

Comment: What is the error output that you are getting when trying ssh to worker node?

Comment: If your worker nodes are in a private subnet then they probably don't have a public IP and shouldn't be accessible by Ssh.  You can access them from a "bastion host" in the public subnet or access them using [Session Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/session-manager-to-linux.html) after making the required configuration changes to support Session Manager.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a workaround. I created an EC2 instance with same VPC which is used by worker node, also used the same security group and Key Pair for newly created EC2 instance. I tried to login to newly created EC2 instance which works like charm ( don't know Why it won't work for worker nodes). Once I logged into the instance tried SSH to worker nodes from there with Private IP which is working as expected.

Again this a workaround. Not sure why I wasn't able to login to worker node.

Comment: were you able to find out the actual reason/solution? I am also facing same issue.

Comment: I'm speculating that your worker nodes are in a private subnet and don't have public IPs.  The new EC2 instance which you created were created in the public subnet and got a public IP so that internet traffic can access it.  This is how it should work.  The instance in the public subnet is your "bastion host".  An alternative to Ssh is to use AWS's [Session Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/session-manager-to-linux.html) to access EC2 instances.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are missing SSH rule for instance's security group or you are using the wrong SSH key to connect to the worker nodes.

Please check from the console your security group id, and add SSH rule from inbound rule like in the screenshot if you don't have it.
[image: SSH rule for security group of worker nodes]

Or you can add same rule via `aws cli` like:

```
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id <security-group-id>  --protocol tcp --port 22 --cidr 0.0.0.0/0
```

Then, by specifying a valid SSH key, you can run the below command to connect to your worker node.

```
ssh -i "ssh-key.pem" ec2-user@<node-external-ip or node-dns-name>
```

If you lost/miss your key, you need to create new stack in cloudformation with new SSH key-pair as described in the following tutorials.

[Creating a Key Pair Using Amazon EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html)
and
[Launch and Configure Amazon EKS Worker Nodes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started.html#eks-launch-workers)

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 3):

When we create Compute, we need to make sure that the **Allow remote access to nodes** is enabled. If this is not chosen, then we cant SSH into the worker nodes.

As well as, EKS itself creates a Security Group which is attached to the worker EC2 machines. I believe you might have missed out enabling **Allow remote access to nodes** in the Step 3.

The workaround is effective because both bastion host and server is in same VPC. That's the rule added by default in the security group.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I remember by default AWS EKS worker nodes don't have public IPs. You can try to create an EC2 instance  with a public IP in the same subnet as your worker nodes are, and than use it like a bastion host to ssh into worker nodes.

Comment: For understanding I enabled ICMP Request and Reply on Security group. I am able to ping the instance after that. There is also rule to allow SSH but when i tried SSH I wont get any response.